# Should [avaloniaui] and [avalonia] be synonymized?

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

The tag descriptions of [avaloniaui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/avaloniaui) and [avalonia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/avalonia) are identical, but they are not [listed as synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms).

I don't have enough score on the tags to [propose it](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/avaloniaui/synonyms) and I can't see any mechanism to tidy it up myself other than to mention it here and hope someone else can help.

Comment: If you are a subject matter expert, it would help to have a description of what you feel should happen. Right now, this is "there's a problem here". It's much more effective to say "There's a problem here. I'm an expert in this area. Here's some more context about the situation. Here's what I think should happen." For example, it's not clear which tag you feel should be a synonym of the other.

Comment: It's called Avalonia UI.  A tag called Avalonia with an identical description is clearly referring to Avalonia UI in an abbreviated way.  I don't know what should happen with the tags.  I'm here to learn that which is why I'm asking.  I assume a synonym should be created.  I don't know about merging or whatever else might be possible to happen.  It seems wrong that there are two unrelated tags that mean the exact same thing.

Comment: A quick search on DuckDuckGo suggests [tag:avalonia] is unique enough to refer to Avalonia UI, I see no point for [tag:avaloniaui] (and if it were, it should be styled as avalonia-ui IMHO, if only for readability).